# Trouble Using CSS Custom Property in Sass/SCSS Variable for Media Query

Tags: css, sass

I'm facing an issue with my Sass/SCSS code where I'm trying to use a CSS custom property within a Sass/SCSS variable for a media query, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
--primary-min-width: 768;
$primary-min-width: var(--primary-min-width);

@media (min-width: $primary-min-width + 1px) {
    /* CSS properties here */
}
```

The intention is to use the value of --primary-min-width as the minimum width for the media query. However, despite checking the variable value and ensuring proper compilation, the media query doesn't seem to behave correctly.

**I've verified that:**

- --primary-min-width is set to the intended value (768).
- My Sass/SCSS code is compiled into CSS.
- The media query is within the same scope as where the variable is
  declared.

Despite these checks, the code isn't producing the expected results. Can anyone spot what might be causing the issue or provide guidance on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After compilation, `$primary-min-width` will be replaced with `var(--primary-min-width)` and it would become an invalid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following code worked just fine:

```
$primary-min-width: 768px;

@media (max-width: $primary-min-width + 10px) {
    .container {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: :root {
 --primary-min-width: 768;
}
must use CSS custom properties (variables) @Leo Rossetti

Comment: Do you know which Sass compiler are you using? Also, have you tried the code the way I passed (declaring the variable like this: $primary-min-width: 768px;) without the --?

Comment: Possibly you need to declare the --primary-min-width variable inside the root, like this: ":root {  --primary-min-width: 768;  }" and then use it directly in the media query: "@media (max-width: var(--primary-min-width) + 10px)".